# Append = TRUE option of the R dump() function

Tags: r, append, dump

For a simulation study I would like to save the results from one sample in an R file and then append this file with the results from the next sample.

To achieve this, I am using the function dump(). To append the file with data from the next simulation, I want to use the append = TRUE option of this function. However, this function is not working for me.

When I simulate data, save it as an R file (by using the dump function) and I do that again with the append = TRUE option the dump function overwrites the data and does not append the file.

What am I doing wrong?

To illustrate the problem, this is my example code:

```
#Simulate data 
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
xy <- data.frame(x,y)

#Dump into R file "xy.R" with option append = TRUE
dump("xy",file="xy.txt", append =TRUE)
rm(xy)  # remove the dataset form current environment

#Retrieve data from file: 
source("xy.R")
xy #100 rows

#Run the code again: Still 100 rows and not 200 as expected. 
#Old data is overwritten, new data is not appended.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually look at the output file?

Dump writes the variable name with the assignment to the file. That means when you ask for `dump("xy")` it will write out

```
xy <- ...
```

and when you run it again, it will append the output to the same file, so it will end up writing

```
xy <- ...
xy <- ...
```

So you've just defined the variable `xy` twice and the last value wins. The `append` option will not append data to every element on the file, it just adds more text to the end of the file. You need to read/merge the data yourself before you dump it again.

Though, if you are dumping a data.frame, you probably would be better of using `write.table` and using `append=T` and `read.table`. That's more likely to be the correct behavior for you. Something like

```
#Simulate data 
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
xy <- data.frame(x,y)

fn<-"xy.txt"
if(file.exists(fn)) {
    xy <- rbind(read.table(fn), xy)
}
write.table(xy,file=fn)
rm(xy)  # remove the dataset form current environment

#Retrieve data from file: 
xy <- read.table(fn)
```

Or perhaps

```
#Simulate data 
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
xy <- data.frame(x,y)

fn<-"xy.txt"
if(file.exists(fn)) {
    write.table(xy, file=fn, row.names=F, col.names=F, append=T)
} else {
    write.table(xy, file=fn, row.names=F, col.names=T)
}
rm(xy)  # remove the dataset form current environment

#Retrieve data from file: 
xy <- read.table(fn, header=T)
```

Comment: Using both `append()` and `rbind()`ing the current results to the previous results might be redundant ... I suspect you want to do one or the other but not both.  (Also, need to be careful with headers when appending ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Good point Ben. I was rushing. I think if i leave the headers unspecified, R will do the right thing. Right?

Comment: @BenBolker Actually, `append=T` on `write.table` was a mess with headers and duplicate row names. Seems like the `read.table` with `rbind` was safer (but perhaps not as efficient)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The write.table function indeed has the more correct  behavior for me (I am calling the function in a batch script and would like to save all output of the parallel simulations in one file). 

I tried the sample code you provided, but I am getting the following error: 
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 6 elements

I assume that this has to do with the fact that, as you also mention, xy <- ... is written down in the first lines of the file. Still, I do not know how to prevent this error.

Comment: @Inga I just made one more edit. It's a bit more fiddly with the `write.table` attributes but If the data set is large, you will not need to read all the existing data first before writing the new data. Good luck.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the edit. I just tried the code and it seems to be working perfectly. This helps a lot, it makes the retrievement of my results much more efficient.